# Inverting amplifier vs noninverting voltage amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

> A big advantage that noninverting voltage amplifier has over the
>   inverter is a much greater input resistance. As a result, this
>   amplifier will readily amplify the voltage from a source that has a
>   large output resistance. In contrast, if an inverter is used, almost
>   all the source voltage will be lost across the large output resistance
>   of the source, as should be apparent from voltage division.

*From textbook: "Schaum's- Basic circuit analysis"*

How those facts ( like noninverting voltage amplifier has  greater input resistance) can be viewed ( through which equation), because the voltage gain doesn't seems to hold the answer?

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTAfa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, \$V_{sig}\$ is the signal of interest. It is a high-impedance source, represented by the series resistance \$R_{sig}\$. This resistance will experience a voltage drop proportional to the current through it, by Ohm's law. Thus, if we want to measure what \$V_{sig}\$ is, without introducing error due to \$R_{sig}\$, we need to measure it with a high-impedance load, that is, a load that does not require much current from the signal source.

It's easy to see how OA2, the non-inverting amplifier accomplishes that. One of the rules of the ideal op-amp is that no current flows through the inputs (input impedance is infinite). Current from \$V_{sig}\$ has no other place to go, so there can be no current. If current through \$R_{sig}\$ is zero, by Ohm's law, so too is its voltage.

On the other hand, there is a path for current in the inverting configuration, OA1, through \$R_{sig}\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$. Another rule of ideal op-amps with negative feedback is that their inputs always have the same voltage. Since the *+* input is connected to ground, the *-* is effectively the same. It isn't *actually* connected to ground, but since our ideal op-amp can sink or source however much current is necessary to keep it at ground potential, we can consider it a [virtual ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground) for the purposes of our analysis.

So, \$V_{sig}\$ is effectively connected to ground through \$R_{sig}\$ and \$R_2\$, forming a voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8DRWA.png)</sup>

The voltage in the middle, the one that would correspond to the input terminal on a non-inverting op-amp that didn't have the source drawn in, isn't \$V_{sig}\$. Rather, it's given by the voltage divider equation:

$$V_{measured} = V_{sig} \frac{R_2}{R_2+R_{sig}}$$

This is the voltage the inverting op-amp amplifies by the textbook gain of \$\frac{-R_3}{R_2}\$. That is:

$$\begin{align} \require{cancel}
V_{out} &= V_{measured} \frac{-R3}{R2}\\
&= V_{sig} \frac{\cancel{R_2}}{R_2+R_{sig}} \frac{-R_3}{\cancel{R_2}}\\
&= V_{sig} \frac{-R_3}{R_2+R_{sig}}
\end{align}$$

If \$R_{sig} \ll R_2\$, then it's not significant. In this case, it's very significant.

Another, perhaps simpler way to think of it is this: \$R_{sig}\$ and \$R_2\$ are in series, so their resistances add. OA1 has no way of knowing that the resistance it sees between its (-) input and \$V_{sig}\$ is two series resistors, and not just one. So effectively, the resistor there is \$20k\Omega\$. The gain of OA1 is effectively:

$$ \frac{-R_3}{R_2+R_{sig}} $$

Which, as you can see, is a term in the equation above.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage gain equation doesn't hold the answer BUT to derive the voltage gain equation you make the very reasonable assumption that both inputs are at the same voltage. If they were not then the op-amp output would be end-stopped into one of the power rails because of its massive open-loop gain.

If -Vin = +Vin AND +Vin is connected to 0V (mid-rail) then -Vin assumes the identity of +Vin and it is also at 0V (mid rail). This assumption is really accurate while the open loop gain of the op-amp is large and this applies on moderate op-amps up to over 10kHz and on fast op-amps to over 1MHz. (These are generalizations of course)

If -Vin is at 0V then the input impedance of the inverting op-amp is Rin.

Looking at +Vin - anything connected to it only has to supply bias current for the input and as a lot of op-amps are JFET (for example), the input impedance into +Vin is very high.

Answer (score 1):

The inverting input acts as a **virtual earth**.

In deriving the voltage gain equation the input current from the signal is almost equal and opposite to the output feedback current. The difference between these two currents is very very small (related to the open loop gain) and it is only this tiny current that is actually input into the inverting input.

In reality this corresponds to a very high input resistance.(virtually 0 input current is required to operate the op amp).

**From the input signal point of view** it "only sees" the input resistor connected from it to a 'virtual earth' point (0V). It is this (external) value that is taken as the input resistance to the op amp. So an inverting amplifier is said to have a lower input resistance.

The non inverting input is just like the inverting input (current wise) **but does not act as a virtual earth**. Hence its input resistance is seen as extremely high (perhaps 100s of Megohms) because it will only take a tiny current.

Comment: Does the "greater input resistance" (as the book says) refered to the resistors which are (in the ideal op amp model) illustrated at the input terminals, inside the triangular circuit symbol for an op amp?

Comment: @user7777777 The input stage inside an op amp is a differential amplifier (long tailed pair). It isn't a resistance as such. Resistance is being defined in terms of how much current will flow for a given voltage.

Comment: I'm grateful to you for your help! Can you please answer to one more question, as I quoted above:"...if an inverter is used, almost all the source voltage will be lost across the large output resistance of the source..." what is that **output resistance**?

Comment: @user7777777 The output resistance from the 'perfect' op amp is (in theory) zero but for practical purposes it will be very low (in the order 10s - 100s ohms) depending on how it is designed . **The amount of current available from the output is quite small (a few mA) so you cannot connect an 8 ohm speaker and expect it to work.** The voltage output swing is limited by the size of the supply voltages to the op amp. (typically the output will reach about 1V less than the supply voltage at either end) so an op amp with 0V - 9V supply will output between 1V and 8V, this is the output saturation.